# When i scroll x direction on line chart, tableview to scrolls same time to up or down

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I've searched and tried some ways but I don't find any solution.

I have a line chart in a tableView. When I scroll x direction on the line chart, tableView to scrolls the same time up. I want to when the user starts dragging on the line chart prevent to tableView scroll.

I tried gestures, scrollView delegate, tableView.isScroll and chartValueSelected but didn't work the way I wanted

What can I do?

Thanks for answers

Comment: Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Yusuf - Did you found any solution?